# C++ fstream is_open() function always returns false

Tags: c++, fstream

I have tried to use open() to open html file in the same directory as the source file. However I dont know why is_open() always return false in my program....
Here is part of my source code

one of the functions to open html file in readHTML.cpp

```
 #include "web.h"
         ...
void extractAllAnchorTags(const char* webAddress, char**& anchorTags, int& numOfAnchorTags)
    {
        ifstream myfile;
        char line[256];
        char content[2048] = "";

        numOfAnchorTags = 0;
        myfile.open(webAddress);
        cout<< myfile.is_open()<<endl;
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {......}
    }
```

header file, web.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct WebNode
{
    char* webAddress; 
    char* anchorText;
    WebNode** hyperlink;
    int numOfHyperlinks;
};

void extractAllAnchorTags(const char* webAddress, char**& anchorTags, int& numOfAnchorTags);
```

another cpp file, callF.cpp

```
#include "web.h"
........
WebNode* createWeb(const char* webAddress, const char* anchorText, int height)
{
    if(height != 0){
       WebNode* webNode = new WebNode;
       char** anchorTags;
       int numOfAnchorTags;
       strcpy(webNode->webAddress,webAddress);
       strcpy(webNode->anchorText,anchorText);
       extractAllAnchorTags(webAddress,anchorTags,numOfAnchorTags);
        \*.........................*\
 }
 .......
```

main.cpp

```
#include "web.h"

     int main(){
        .............
        cin >> filename;  // index.html   would be input during running.
        Page = createWeb(filename, anchorText, max_height);
        .............
      }
```

my main.cpp just call createWeb once
However what i get that myfile.is_open() always returns false since it prints out 0 in my console of eclipse...
I have no idea why even I try to reset my argument directory to my workspace
or I put my html file inside debug folder .. it still returns false.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write to uninitialized pointers:

```
struct WebNode
{
    char* webAddress; 
    char* anchorText;
    WebNode** hyperlink;
    int numOfHyperlinks;
};

// ...

WebNode* webNode = new WebNode;
strcpy(webNode->webAddress,webAddress);
```

The pointer `webNode->webAddress` does not currently point anywhere. To fix this, change its type from `char *` to `std::string`, and use string assignment to copy the string contents.

Your copying to uninitialized pointer causes undefined behaviour which may result in memory corruption and so on, so the rest of your program appears to fail.

Also you should redesign `extractAllAnchorTags` to not use pointers.

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me.
I try to swap the order of my code to avoid such memory corruption.
Thanks. You save my time a lot

Answer (score 0):

The class `ifstream` cannot open web sites. It only opens files. You need to use a library such as CURL.

Comment: What if I want to read the source code of the html file since I need to read the content inside the html source? and I try to create another program which is just simply opening html file and it returns true to me... I have no idea why this would happen..

Comment: I am assuming the variable `webAddress` is a URL. Am I correct?

Comment: webAddress is the html name , for example, index.html

Comment: Are you opening a file or a URL?

Comment: opening a file, I put the index.html in the same folder with the source code.
and then I use webAddress as the variable which stores 'index.html'  as character string array.
Then I am supposed to open the file to get some information of the source code of that index.html file